# How to Replace a QWidget with a QML QQuickView?

Tags: qt, qml

My current user interface is made with a QWidget, but I have made a nicer one in QML. I've already converted all the slots and signals to use a class that is basically a wrapper for the QML QQuickView, but because my main window has a menu bar and a dock, I would place the primary widget with `setCentralWidget()` which cannot be used with the `QQuickView`. How would I instantiate a QML front end so that it can be interpreted as a widget and set as central?

I am using qt 5.2.1 and visual studio 2010.

Comment: `QQuickWidget` is in 5.3, not 5.2. I can't use that.

Comment: Wolf gives right answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer is `QWidget::createWindowContainer` in Qt 5.2.

[source](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/02/19/introducing-qwidgetcreatewindowcontainer/)